# How can Firefox suddenly stop working on Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Firefox has suddenly stopped working on Ubuntu 14.04 machine,the strange part is that the computer seems to reject it no matter what, I tried re-installing it from the terminal, but it didn't run after that either, I then removed it and installed it again from both terminal and Software center and Installing again (twice), and it did not work either, then i tried running it from the terminal and it did not work either, the terminal gave me the following :

```
(process:7212): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:7212): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:7212): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:7212): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:7212): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
Could not create gnome accelerators directory `/home/xxxxx/.gnome2/accels': Permission denied
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I faced this issue too, and the answer below solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a permissions problem: try to change the permissions of the folder by typing:

```
sudo  chown -R yourUsername:yourUsername /home/ubuntu
sudo  chmod -R 664 /home/yourUsername/.gnome2/accels/
```

You should now be able to open firefox.

OR

Before doing `sudo  chown -R yourUsername:yourUsername /home/ubuntu`, you could try just creating the `accels` folder with the command `sudo mkdir /home/yourUsername/.gnome2/accels`. That might be sufficient, because the error just means that Firefox is unable to create that folder or able to make changes to it. If Firefox still does not open, use `sudo  chmod -R 664 /home/yourUsername/.gnome2/accels/`